# Unhandled exceptions on a managed thread which functions as UI thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception

I recently received a piece of (horrible) code to maintain. One of the problems is that the unhandled exception handlers are not working at all. I am starting to understand why, but it raises questions I'd like to understand more about.

In short, the application is started by a static Main method with `STAThread` attribute. On this thread a LoginScreen is shown (on the STAThread). When the user enters his credentials, **another thread** is created, which launches the actual user interface. So, the actual user interface runs on a managed thread (which has the appartment state set to ApartmentState.STA).

The subscriptions to the events `Application.ThreadException` and `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` are set on the "real" STAThread, while the actual user interface runs on a "different" STA thread.

The problem I ran into is that unhandled exceptions are **not** being caught be the unhandled exception handlers.

When I **also** subscripe to the above described events on the "different" STA thread, then unhandled exception **are** caught by the unhandled exception handlers.

I never realised this before (I also never ran a user interface on a different thread then the "main" thread...), but is it mandatory to subscribe to the `Application.ThreadException` (and/or `AppDomain.CurrentAppDomain.UnhandledException`) on the **same** thread that instantiates the user interface? Or the same thread that calls `Application.Run`? Both seem unlikely, but clearly there is a restriction on which thread I am supposed to subscribe to the events.

I would really appreciate a bit of more background on this specific topic.

If I am not making sense, or doing a poor job describing my question please leave a comment.

Original question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34067995/unable-to-catch-unhandledexceptions)

Comment: Some exceptions can't be caught, what exception specifically is happening that you aren't catching?

Comment: @RonBeyer Just the usual programming errors, null reference exceptions e.g.

Comment: AppDomain unhandled exception handlers are thread agnostic, so what thread you register the event handler makes no difference.

Comment: The word "thread" in Application.ThreadException is not accidental.  [Read this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsui_team/archive/2012/10/31/debugging-windows-forms-application-hangs-during-systemevents.userpreferencechanged.aspx) to see why displaying UI on multiple threads is very dangerous.

Comment: @Will ok, so the only restriction then is the `Application.ThreadException`? I doesn't work because the Application.Run is done on 1 thread, but the actual user interface is running on another thread. Or is it irrelevant on which thread the Application.Run is called? As long as the event handlers are set on the same thread that run the actually UI?

Comment: @HansPassant haha fair point. I already read on MSDN "This event allows your Windows Forms application to handle otherwise unhandled exceptions that occur in Windows Forms threads". So on which thread I call Application.Run has **nothing** to do with it?

Comment: @bas I don't know about A.TE, never used that in a multithreaded environment :/ I also can't tell you if some asshole is swallowing your exceptions somewhere you don't know about.  But I do know that if an unhandled exception leaves the top of a call stack from a thread, this event is guaranteed to fire in the appdomain where the thread was created.  That's your executing assembly's appdomain, most often.  Is this bad code spinning up new appdomains you don't know about?

Comment: Hmm, reading the docs they appear to have changed some things which might affect whether or not it executes.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx read the bits about corrupted state and reliability.  That might be your issue, if you're running 4+.

Comment: @Will, I am sure there are no AppDomains are created in code. But I also never bothered with Application.ThreadException. I don't think it's mandatory with a WPF application, but it seems to be for a WinForms application. Running .net45 by the way. Will have a look at the msdn link. thx